# Trouble changing X and Y data when using Jframe

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, jframe

Firstly I would like to say that I am a beginner with java, so I would like to apologise in advance if some of this post does not make sense.

I am creating a GUI based program. The program allows the user to load either a CSV, JSON or XML file. The program then reads each line of the file, splits each type of data and then parses it into an array list. This list of data is then saved to an object.

The aim of the program is to then manipulate the data (for example, create the averages of data, minimum values of data, maximum values of data) and to plot the manipulated data to a graph.

So the user loads a file, then they click a button to plot a graph.

I am having trouble displaying TIME along the X axis of the graph. Below is a screenshot of my GUI. As you can see, the graph is plotting the TEMP data just fine, however I am unsure where the graph is getting the data from for the X axis (it is going up in increments of 5000).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/deDkj.jpg

I think one of my main problems here is understanding how to correctly use the LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormatter libraries. This is because of how the time/date are stored in the CSV/JSON/XML files. Here are the first few lines of the CSV file to help you understand the problem.

```
millis,stamp,datetime,light,temp,vcc
1000, 1273010254, 2010/5/4 21:57:34, 333, 78.32, 3.54
2000, 1273010255, 2010/5/4 21:57:35, 333, 78.32, 3.92
3000, 1273010256, 2010/5/4 21:57:36, 344, 78.32, 3.95
4000, 1273010257, 2010/5/4 21:57:37, 326, 78.32, 3.97
```

I have researched Jframe and tried my best to understand how to implement it. However, I am struggling trying to find relevant information on how to use Jframe when using data from an array list.

Below I will share with you some of classes and code.

**Light Chart Class**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.*;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;


public class LightBarChart extends ApplicationFrame
{

public LightBarChart(String title) {
    super(title);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

//arraylist for LIGHT
private ArrayList<Double> light = new ArrayList<Double>();


public ArrayList<Double> getLight() {
    return light;
}

public void setLight(ArrayList<Double> light) {
    this.light = light;
}



private XYDataset createDataset()
{
    XYSeries xyseries1 = new XYSeries("Light");
    int i = 1;
    for(double d:light){
        xyseries1.add(i, d);//adds all the element of the araylist into the xyseries
        i++;
    }

    ///XYSeries xyseries2 = new XYSeries("Light");
    //i = 1;
    //for(double d:light){
        //xyseries2.add(i, d);//adds all the element of the araylist into the xyseries
        //i++;
    //}     

    XYSeriesCollection xyseriescollection = new XYSeriesCollection();
    xyseriescollection.addSeries(xyseries1);
    //xyseriescollection.addSeries(xyseries2);

    return xyseriescollection;
}

private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset xydataset)
{
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Line Chart Showing Light", "X", "Y", xydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)jfreechart.getPlot();
    xyplot.setDomainPannable(true);
    xyplot.setRangePannable(true);
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer xylineandshaperenderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer)xyplot.getRenderer();
    xylineandshaperenderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
    xylineandshaperenderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
    NumberAxis numberaxis = (NumberAxis)xyplot.getRangeAxis();
    numberaxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    return jfreechart;
}

public JPanel createDemoPanel()
{
    JFreeChart jfreechart = createChart(createDataset());
    ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(jfreechart);
    chartpanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
    return chartpanel;
}

public void plot()
{
    //super(s);
    JPanel jpanel = createDemoPanel();
    jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 450));
    setContentPane(jpanel);     
    this.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(this);
    this.setVisible(true);



}
}
```

**CSV READER CLASS**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CSVReader {

//create a class that will hold arraylist which will have objects representing all lines of the file

private List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
private String path;


public List<Data> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}
public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

//next job is to create a method to read through the csv stored in the path
//and create the list of data and store in the dataList

public void readCSV() throws IOException{

    //i will create connection with the file, in the path
    BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));  

    String line = null;
    line = in.readLine();

    while((line = in.readLine())!=null){

        //we have each line in the variable 'line'

        //we need to split and store in the temporary variable and create an object


        String[] splits = line.split(",");// line.split("\\s*(=>|,|\\s)\\s*");

        long millis = Long.parseLong(splits[0].trim());
        long stamp = Long.parseLong(splits[1].trim());
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/M/d H:m:s");
        LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(splits[2].trim(), formatter);
        LocalDate date = datetime.toLocalDate();
        LocalTime time = datetime.toLocalTime();
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/M/d HH:mm:ss" );
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( "2010/5/4 21:57:34" , f );
        double light = Double.parseDouble(splits[3].trim());
        double temp = Double.parseDouble(splits[4].trim());
        double vcc = Double.parseDouble(splits[5].trim());


        Data d = new Data(millis,stamp,datetime,light,temp,vcc);//uses constructor

        dataList.add(d);

    }end of while loop

}
}
```

**DATA Class**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Data {

//define the attributes for your data here

private long millis;
private long stamp;
private LocalDateTime datetime;
//private String datetime;
private double light;
private double temp;    
private double vcc;

public Data() {}



public Data(long millis, long stamp, LocalDateTime datetime, double light, double temp, double vcc) {
    super();
    this.millis = millis;
    this.stamp = stamp;
    this.datetime = datetime;
    this.light = light;
    this.temp = temp;
    this.vcc = vcc;
}



public long getMillis() {
    return millis;
}

public void setMillis(long millis) {
    this.millis = millis;
}

public long getStamp() {
    return stamp;
}

public void setStamp(long stamp) {
    this.stamp = stamp;
}

public LocalDateTime getDatetime() {
    return datetime;
}

public void setDatetime(LocalDateTime datetime) {
    this.datetime = datetime;
}

public double getLight() {
    return light;
}

public void setLight(double light) {
    this.light = light;
}

public double getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

public void setTemp(double temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}

public double getVcc() {
    return vcc;
}

public void setVcc(double vcc) {
    this.vcc = vcc;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data [millis=" + millis + ", stamp=" + stamp + ", datetime=" + datetime + ", light=" + light + ", temp="
            + temp + ", vcc=" + vcc + "]";
}



}
```